# Questions for Loop in R (solution found)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, lapply

I have a code that applies to one data frame that has temperature data for one year.

I am trying to write a loop to apply my code to multiple data sets (for now only two -> so two countries). For this I read the yearly country data (csv file) as a list using:

```
setwd("/Users/lisak/Desktop/WeatherDataFiles")
files <- list.files(path=getwd(), pattern=".csv")
dfList <- lapply(files, function(f) {
  df <- read.csv(f, header=TRUE)
})
```

With my loop I am trying to create a new variable (the mean of the monthly temperature per weather station(STN_NAME)), which works (I receive a list of 2 data frames for yearlymean). 
But when I do the second loop to split the data into months, I receive a list of 2 data frames but both contain the data from the last data set in the loop.

```
yearlymean <- list()
monthlymean <- list()
for (i in 1:length(dfList)) {
  yearlymean[[i]] <- aggregate((dfList[[i]])[,"MAX"] ,list(STN_NAME=(dfList[[i]])$STN_NAME, MONTH=(dfList[[i]])$MONTH), mean)
  for (j in 1:length(yearlymean)) {
  monthlymean[[j]]  <- split(yearlymean[[i]], as.factor((yearlymean[[i]])$MONTH))
 }
  }
```

I'm not sure what I am missing in the 2nd loop so that it doesnt save the split data of the first data frame.
Also, is there a nicer way to code this?
Thanks

The whole code:

```
library(GSODR)
Moz <- get_GSOD(years = 2015, country = "Mozambique") # retreiving data from package
Zim <- get_GSOD(years = 2015, country = "Zimbabwe")   # retreiving data from package
write.csv(Moz, file ="Mozambique_2015.csv") # saving data to WeatherDataFiles folder
write.csv(Zim, file = "Zimbabwe_2015.csv")  # saving data to WeatherDataFiles folder

setwd("/Users/lisak/Desktop/WeatherDataFiles")
files <- list.files(path=getwd(), pattern=".csv")
dfList <- lapply(files, function(f) {
  df <- read.csv(f, header=TRUE)

yearlymean <- list()
monthlymean <- list()
for (i in 1:length(dfList)) {
  yearlymean[[i]] <- aggregate((dfList[[i]])[,"MAX"] ,list(STN_NAME=(dfList[[i]])$STN_NAME, MONTH=(dfList[[i]])$MONTH), mean)
  for (j in 1:length(yearlymean)) {
  monthlymean[[j]]  <- split(yearlymean[[i]], as.factor((yearlymean[[i]])$MONTH))
 }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this will work given that I do not exactly know how your data look. 
In the following, I assume this structure:

```
  year month day        temp
1 2000     1   1 -0.17489752
2 2000     1   2 21.70812842
3 2000     1   3 -6.39391558
4 2000     1   4 -0.05699615
5 2000     1   5  4.37288935
6 2000     1   6  0.20555128
```

Then I would use the data.table package. With `bigtable = rbindlist(list)` you can row bind all tables from you list. 
The next step is simply

```
#for yearly mean
bigtable[, .(mean = mean(temp)), by = c("year")]
# for monthly mean
bigtable[, .(mean = mean(temp)), by = c("month")]
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for your help! I had a few things that were missing in my question, it wasnt very clear. My question is more about the loop, especially the 2nd for loop where I am not getting 2 unique data frames in my list.